# How can I implement full disk encryption for a disk containing Ubuntu with plausible deniability?

Tags: encryption

I would like to have a disk that:

- has Ubuntu installed
- is fully encrypted
- is setup in such a way as to make denial of the existence of the Ubuntu install plausible

Truecrypt provides the last two features but only for Windows: http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=sys-encryption-supported-os

The alternate installer for Ubuntu provides the first two features but not the last.

I imagine that plausible deniability would be achieved by, at least:

- Having two installs of Ubuntu and 2 passphrases (or keyfiles) which would unencrypt each one.
- Moving any unencrypted data (such as /boot) onto a USB stick

Are there any programs out there which support this feature set for Ubuntu?

Comment: Why would you want to deny that you have Ubuntu installed?  The purpose of the plausible deniability is to hide your data.

Comment: @psusi What is the difference? What procedure are you aware of that allows plausible deniability for encrypted data but not the OS under which that data is written?

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

http://and1equals1.blogspot.ro/2009/10/encrypting-your-hdd-with-plausible.html

I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use the above tutorial but for an additional OS installed in the free space (under cryptsetup - as described in the tutorial - which does not create a LUKS header) left after installing your main decoy OS.